# append two incomplete lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

L = [a, b, c|_]. - an example of an incomplete list. how do I append two of these? How do I reverse an incomplete list? Can someone give me tips how to deal with these in general?

append([x|t],y,[x|r]):-append(t,y,r). This is how two lists are appended.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `append`? As in, `append(L, L2, R)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for instance

```
?- A=[1,2,3|X], B=[a,b,c|Y], X=B.
A = [1, 2, 3, a, b, c|Y],
X = B, B = [a, b, c|Y].
```

These patterns are of little utility.

As @Daniel Lyons suggests, you can as well use append/3

```
?- A=[1,2,3|X], B=[a,b,c|Y], append(A,B,C).
A = [1, 2, 3],
X = [],
B = [a, b, c|Y],
C = [1, 2, 3, a, b, c|Y]
```

You can see the difference between those patterns: first *directly* binds X to B (1 inference), while append requires a number of inferences equal to first list length, to reach the tail before binding.

You can read more about incomplete data structures [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node180.html). The most useful pattern is `difference lists`, the base for [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg).

Comment: Your second version using `append/3` does not terminate! You can see that Prolog want's to answer more from the lack of a `.` at the end. I am sure @Dan did not mean that.

Comment: Oh, it might be. :) Honestly I didn't and still don't understand quite what the difficulty is that the OP is having. Lists are lists. I wouldn't expect an incomplete data structure to work in every situation a complete one does (or vice-versa).

Comment: @Dan: It is a frequently recurring assertion in textbooks (like AoP) that differences are so much more efficient - which is true if they are used in the way of (the internal translation of) DCGs. But explicit usage is so restricted (e.g., you cannot unify two difference for the purpose of comparison) and textbooks are not very clear on that. Time would be much better spent if DCG usage (phrase/2, not even phrase/3) would be taught instead.

Comment: @false Thanks for expanding on that. As you may have noticed since correcting me more than a few times on here that I'm quite interested in DCGs and have gotten much better at them over the years. But I have poured nearly zero energy into raw difference lists. I can attest to your assertion: this has not been a significant handicap, though it makes questions like this one seem ill-posed to me in my ignorance. I'd like to know more, but DCGs seem to suffice 99% of the time, so I haven't.